# Error importing firebase to React Native Expo

Tags: firebase, react-native, expo

I want to authorize the FireBase application in React Native Expo, but I have an error.

I am using FireBase version 8.2.34 ( installed with the command "`npm install firebase@8.2.3`" ).

Code ( `firebase.js` ) :

```js
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import * as firebase from "firebase";
// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = { ... };

// Initialize Firebase
let app;
if (firebase.apps.length === 0) {
  app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
} else {
  app = firebase.app()
}
```

ExpoGO App error ( in line №2 ):

```
Uncaught Error
Can't find variable: IDBIndex
...
<global>
...\firebase.js:2
...
```

UPD:
Also, I have a problem with importing FireStore.

Answer (score 0):

**Note:use compat while importing.**
i suggest to have these in one seprate file. (use web configuration)

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    databaseURL: "",
    projectId: "",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "",
    appId: "",
    measurementId: ""
};
const app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export const db = app.firestore();
```